# incomplete data transfer in python socket

Tags: python

I am creating a client server program on which client downloads server's files. it works fine in localhost, but the problem occurs in except localhost connection. I've tried googling but none of the solutions(from previously suggested to the same problem) works.

Here is my code:

```
def upload(sock): # server.py
    filename = str(sock.recv(4096)).split(' end')[0]
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        sock.send('YES')
        sock.send(str(os.path.getsize(filename)) + ' end')
        foo = open(filename, 'rb')
        upbytes = foo.read(4096)
        sock.sendall(upbytes)
        while upbytes != '':
            upbytes = foo.read(4096)
            sock.sendall(upbytes)
        foo.close()
        print "\tUpload Complete !"
    else:
        sock.send('NO')


def download(sock, filename): #client.py
    sock.send(filename + ' end')
    if sock.recv(4096) == 'YES':
        filesize = int(str(sock.recv(4096)).split(' end')[0])
        print filesize, 'filesize'
        foo = open('downloaded_' + os.path.basename(filename), 'wb')
        downbytes = sock.recv(4096)
        foo.write(downbytes)
        downlen = len(downbytes)
        while downlen < filesize:
            downbytes = sock.recv(4096)
            if not downbytes:
                break
            foo.write(downbytes)
            downlen += len(downbytes)
        foo.close()
        print 'filesize', filesize, 'downlen', downlen
        print "\t\tDownload Complete !\n"
    else:
        print "\t\tFile not found ! <" + filename + '>'
```

I've tried different solutions but none of them worked!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks. It's really important to tag a question correctly - adding the [vb.net] tag isn't appropriate in this case as the question seems to relate solely to python code. Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidWilson thankyou sir, for guiding me with that. but more importantly it would be great to know the solution of this problem. i am stuck here to move further :(

Comment: If you run `python -m http.server` (Python 3) that will host files from the current directory for you.

Comment: @NickT does http.server supports sending and receiving messages like socket does(with send(string) recv(string) ??

Comment: HTTP supports messages. Sockets **do not support messages**, they are **streams**.

Comment: I guess someone with python knowledge should be able to help - I'm a VB.net person.

Comment: yeah any such thing that can help me make command based program to perform specific tasks as per command/stream recognized ? beside downloading files !

Comment: @Bhuwanpandey SSH?

Comment: some sort of :)

Answer (score 0):

Sockets have no concept of "messages" as you are using them. If you put `'YES'` then `'some_filename'` onto the socket, it's chance (helped by doing a local connection) that when you do a `recv(4096)` that it shows up as just `'YES'` and not `'YESsome_f'...`.

You need to either parse the stream into the messages yourself (store data received), or add a layer of something that has messages (like HTTP or ZMQ).

If you want to host files, [`python -m http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) can do that for you.

Comment: why is it that it works on localhost and not in other? its not that files are not transferring, it is only transmitted incomplete ! confused that is socket the only thing i've to work with or are there any alternatives for what i want to do with socket